# URL structure for iAds

Tags: ios, iad, ads

A call of help from iOS developers out there. I am trying to recognize different Ad Networks in mobile phones. For this the only data available to me are the URL from HTTP headers from the Apps and browser. I could identify certain Ad Networks like Admob, Jumptap easily with the url structure. For example, the admob one is something like this:

```
http://a.admob.com/*
http://p.admob.com/*
```

But I can't figure how to identify iAds from Apple. Does anyone know what kind of URLs these produce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay.  I've done some snooping into the matter with the aid of a couple of iPhones and my local firewall/web proxy server here, and this is what I've found:

Alas, no hostnames to help you, either.  The requests for both banners and ad units have IP addresses in the URLs, not hostnames.  Which IP addresses, incidentally, appear to be Akamai content distribution servers all over the place; the addresses I've seen have mostly been in 70.183.* and 174.*, but no guarantees on that point.

The URL structures I've seen are quite complex.  Stripping out and replacing with ~ the parts which I've observed varying over the few hundred requests I've sniffed gives me this as a URL pattern for a banner request:

```
http://~~~~~~~~/~~~~~~~.ad/AdUnit/WebArchive.webarchive
http://~~~~~~~~/~~~~~~~.ad/Creatives/~~~~~~/HTMLBanner/WebArchive.webarchive
http://~~~~~~~~/~~~~~~~.ad/Creatives/~~~~~~/ImageBanners/~~~~~~~.png
```

And this for an actual ad being downloaded after a banner touch:

```
http://~~~~~~~~/adunits/~~~~~~~~~~~/1.ad/AdUnit/~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What may be of more use, if you don't have any need to distinguish ad banner displays from clickthroughs, is to look for the user agent, which for all the banner requests is "AdSheet/1.0".  (Noting of course that there are multiple banner requests for any given banner being downloaded - all the different sizes the app writer indicates to iAd that he wants to use; and also that this is NOT the case when ad content is being downloaded, which just uses the iPhone's regular user agent.  But if all you're wanting to do is detect that iAd is in use, etc., that probably doesn't matter so much.)

Comment: thanks for putting the effort into helping me out. it really seems to be complex as compared to other ad networks. appreciate your help :)

Comment: also could you tell me which Apps/Sites did you use to check these iAds?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it uses https with [Akamai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) for the content distribution. Checking the iAd framework for text strings reveals `https://iadsdk.apple.com/adserver`, which looks promising as the base address from which the list of ads are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to snoop the actual urls that the device is using. There are many ways to do this, some involving Jailbreaking, but the way [described on TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/02/21/how-to-inspect-ioss-http-traffic-without-spending-a-dime/) seems to be pretty good. This way you can observe many ads and look for common traits.

Comment: thanks this seems to be the only way for now. can you tell me of some prominent apps (free) that use the iad platform?

Comment: That's probably not going to work particularly well, unless the ads themselves are served using plain http rather than https. Chances are all your proxy will see is a CONNECT to whatever server Apple is using to serve the ads from, and then a bunch of encrypted traffic. No URLs. OTOH, maybe just the host names are good enough for this purpose.

Comment: I would just go down the top free list on the iTunes App Store. Off the top of my head, check out the NYTimes.